# Python str = str + value is slow

Tags: python, lag, assignment-operator

I am writing 2 Mbyte file line by line and using `string` variable to populate the data line by line first

When i did in loops `str = str + new_data` it took couple seconds to process the script.

Once i changed to `str += new data` script finishes instantly.

Though `+=` was a shortcut for same command they added in newer versions.

Why first syntax causes substantially more time to process?

P.S. When i needed to write 50 MByte file script was never finishing in minutes, i suspect that was a reason.

Comment: `+=`  is optimized in CPython to modify the otherwise immutable `str` in place. That's not something you should rely on, though. If you are doing this in a loop, you should collect all the `new_data` values in a list and use `str = ''.join(new_values)` to update the list all at once.

Comment: @chepner assigning lines to list in loop is faster than assigning to string? Please post answer.

Comment: A *series* of such updates would be quadratic in the length of the string, as each `str = str + new_data` copies the contents of *both* the ever-lenghthening `str` and `new_data` into a new string. Appending to a list, on the other hand, takes (amortized) constant time, and the call to `''.join` is just linear in the total length of the strings to be joined.

Comment: On top of that, you can use an iterable as an argument to string.join - you dont need to keep the list in memory

Comment: @Lesiak could you provide code example?